How to redirect based on the previous routes in laravel
There are two ways to delete a post in my app:
way 1:
urls:
/ -> posts/{post} -> posts/{post}
names:
home -> posts.show -> posts.destroy
way 2:
urls:
/posts -> /posts/{post} -> posts/{post}
names:
posts.index -> posts.show -> posts.destroy
how can redirect the user back to where he came from after deleting?
I want him to be redirected to home in way 1 and to my posts in way 2.
I've seen that it could be done using a hidden input field like this:
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="home">
These are my routes:
Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'latestPosts'])->name('home');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);
});

but this won't really work because both ways are using the same blade view show, so should I just create a separate view for each one of them or is there a better way to do so?

they are talking about redirecting to the previous location, I don't want that I want to go to the location before it (or have a way to redirect to a specific location based on a condition).

@AhmadAhmad, you don't need to create separate view because even though both way are using same blade but the http request are different.Share your route file. And state and state after deletion where you want user to redirect.

I included my routes, but didn't quite understand what do you mean by state and state after deletion.

I have posted my solution,please check and let me know in case you face any difficulty to solve the issue.

I have faced this similar situation in my own project a few months ago. So I will suggest you to track the user navigation persistently through session to track the URL-state.
Follow these steps.
Step 1 :-
For for / URL, set this session(['redirect_url' => 'index']); to the respected controller method.
And for /post URL , set this session(['redirect_url' => 'post']); to the respected controller method.
Step 2 :-
Then you can set the redirect-url in hidden input field of the form like this.
    @if (session('redirect_url') == "index")
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="index">
    @elseif (session('redirect_url') == "post")
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="post">
    @endif

Step 3 :-
Finally ,you can get the redirect_url value by the two ways.

by accessing the input hidden field of the form.
by directly accessing the session-value

It is demo to retrieve the session value by directly accessing it.
Get the session-value in the posts/{post}(named posts.destroy) controller method and redirect the user with the following logic.
if(session('redirect_url') == "index")
{
  return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Deletion completed 
  successfully'); //redirected to `home`
}
elseif(session('redirect_url') == "post")
{
   return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Deletion completed 
   successfully'); //redirected to `posts.index`
}

Try this, it will work for sure.

You can use redirect()->back() to take the user back to the page they just came from.
You can read more about Redirects in Laravel here.
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Do your deletion actions here

    // Redirect back to the previous page
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Item deleted successfully');
}

If you want to redirect back to a specific page, pass the URL or route in redirect()
public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Do your deletion actions here
    
        // Redirect back to a specific page
        return redirect('/path/to/url')->with('success', 'Item deleted successfully');
    }


deletion button is in show view file (in show route), and deletion will direct user to destroy route... using back() function here will make him go back to show route which is not accessible any more because the resource is gone.
so I don't want to go back to previous route but to a specified route based on some condition or user activity.

@AhmadAhmad What are your conditions you want your redirects to follow?

This is what I'm asking about, I need a condition (or anyway) to get user back to /home if he came from there and to /index if he came from there, but the problem is these routes aren't directly previous to delete route so I can't use back() function to get back to them.

So when you are in show route you can shore previous URL in cache or send as param for delete route and after deleting item you can get the URL and back to previous url.
